# Make all around rounded object from curve

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a sculpture ad I've tried using meshes and extruding but I don't have enough knowledge to do it that way yet since I am a beginner. Now I'm trying to use curves to trace it. I've traced the outline but I don't know how to make a mesh out of it because I need it to be round and if I extrude the curve I end up with flat face on the Y axis.

[image: Here's a picture of the outline] and [image: here's a picture of the sculpture]. Does anyone know how I can make the sculpture out of the curve? Or does anyone know another easy way to model this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw its profile with as few vertices as possible:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Cut in half, give it a *Mirror* modifier, add edge loops to sharpen some edges, move some edges to round some parts:

[image]

*Edit:* From your current topology, if you want to round the shape and sharpen the edges you need to move some edges and add support edge loops:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hello! For the past few days I've tried modeling this sculpture at least 5 times from scratch and I'm still failing. The topography ends up all kinds of crooked and weird. Would you mind sharing with me your file or maybe explaining a little bit more the steps after the mirror modifier? I'm having a lot of trouble with making it look actually round.

Comment: it will look round if you give it a Subdivision Surface modifier, and to keep some edges sharp you need to add support edge loops

Comment: please share your last attempt so that I can take a look to what you've done: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I have my second attempt saved but I didn't even save the following attempts because they turned out worse and not saving forces me to start from scratch again and practice more. In this attempt, I already applied the subsurface modifier and did a limited dissolve to lessen the number of faces (I plan to use the model in a game so I try to keep things as low poly as possible). https://pasteall.org/blend/44ddae1ea5da4f84bd76a3ada3beac08

Comment: why is the topology so bad? Don't apply any Subdivision Surface unless you're satisfied and unless you really need to, and any way always keep a version with the Subdivision unapplied. But here the topology looks like if you've used a remesh tool, why did you?

Comment: The topology is wonky because I've dissolved some faces because I need the model to be low poly. But regardless of that, I don't know how to make it look cylindrical. https://pasteall.org/blend/9f08241e07ed4dcb947bd4c2c2f70bc7 Here is an attempt I worked on since I replied to your comment. The faces still look flat on the sides. I don't know how to fix it :( I'm sorry to bother you this much but I'm genuinely at a loss.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so so so MUCH!!!!!!!